# How can I represent this JSON response to Java Class?

Tags: java, json, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

What is the right way to represent this JSON Response to Java Class. I'm using jsonschema2pojo to pass json to java class but I have a problem with the "timeline" key, because its value is an object and every day a new key value pair is added, well, this is the json response

```
"timelines": {
            "confirmed": {
                "latest": 434,
                "timeline": {
                    "2020-03-05T00:00:00Z": 4,
                    "2020-03-06T00:00:00Z": 4,
                    "2020-03-07T00:00:00Z": 4,
                    "2020-03-08T00:00:00Z": 8,
                    "2020-03-09T00:00:00Z": 8,
                    "2020-03-10T00:00:00Z": 13,
                    "2020-03-11T00:00:00Z": 23,
                    "2020-03-12T00:00:00Z": 23,
                    "2020-03-13T00:00:00Z": 43,
                    "2020-03-14T00:00:00Z": 61,
                    "2020-03-15T00:00:00Z": 74,
                    "2020-03-16T00:00:00Z": 155,
                    "2020-03-17T00:00:00Z": 201,
                    "2020-03-18T00:00:00Z": 238,
                    "2020-03-19T00:00:00Z": 238,
                    "2020-03-20T00:00:00Z": 434
                }
            },
```

Since this "2020-03-05T00:00:00Z" is created dynamically, how can I iterate over there and how can I make a java model base on this json?

Comment: I recommend you start here. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm

Comment: You can also try this https://quicktype.io/. Just pick java and get your model generated.

Answer (score 3):

Make `timeline` a `Map<LocalDateTime, Integer>`, choosing `TreeMap` (auto sorting in date time order) or `LinkedHashMap` (iterates in insertion order) depending on your needs.

Comment: FWIW, with the `Z` this is an instant.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- good point; there is no place on the planet whose time zone is Zulu.